# Apply hover out ease effect using css animation

Tags: html, css, animation, css-transitions

On this [LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/th6andfn/2/) you can see how animation works in each `div` moves its image and gives `opacity:1` to text.

When hover-off, naturally all styles get back to their initial state directly, but I want them to do it smoothly(ease), instead of setting all initial styles at the same time with no progress.

Here it is related animation code:

```
#highlights div[class*="high-"]:hover > p {
    -webkit-animation:downOp 0.3s ease-in 0s forwards;
    -ms-animation:downOp 0.3s ease-in 0s forwards;
    animation:downOp 0.3s ease-in 0s forwards;
}
#highlights div[class*="high-"]:hover > .image {
    -webkit-animation:imgTrans 5s ease-out 0s forwards;
    -ms-animation:imgTrans 5s ease-out 0s forwards;
    animation:imgTrans 5s ease-out 0s forwards;
}
@-webkit-keyframes downOp {
    0% {
        opacity:0.7;
    }
    100% {
        opacity:1;
    }
}
@-ms-keyframes downOp {
    0% {
        opacity:0.7;
    }
    100% {
        opacity:1;
    }
}
@keyframes downOp {
    0% {
        opacity:0.7;
    }
    100% {
        opacity:1;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes imgTrans {
    0% {
        margin-right: 0;
    }
    100% {
        margin-right: -50px;
    }
}
@-ms-keyframes imgTrans {
    0% {
        margin-right: 0;
    }
    100% {
        margin-right: -50px;
    }
}
@keyframes imgTrans {
    0% {
        margin-right: 0;
    }
    100% {
        margin-right: -50px;
```

}
}

Comment: We're lacking the un`:hover`ed styles. Are you already setting the animation property there?

Comment: Which animation setting? I am afraid do not know what you are referring to. There it is the entire related code, as well on the Jsfiddle. Is it s.thing missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use css `transform` instead of css `animation`! It will automatically handle hover-out effect!

- [See your fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/th6andfn/5/)
- [See my modified effect jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/th6andfn/4/)

**html**

```
<article id="highlights">
    <div class="high-rinoplastia">
        <div class="image"></div>
        <p><strong>Rinoplastia</strong>

            <br> <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod</span>

        </p>
    </div>
</article>
```

**css**

```
    #highlights {
    min-height: 525px;
    width: 1170px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
#highlights div[class*="high-"] {
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.28);
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    height: 150px;
    margin: 10px;
    position: relative;
    width: calc(33% - 20px);
    overflow: hidden;
}
#highlights .image {
    height:100%;
    transition:all 4s ease;
}
#highlights p {
    background-color: white;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 60px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    opacity:0.7;
    transition:all 0.6s ease;
}
#highlights span {
    display: block;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin: 2px;
}
#highlights:hover p {
    opacity:1;
}
#highlights:hover .image {
    transform:all 5s ease;
    margin-right: -50px;
}
#highlights .high-rinoplastia .image {
    background: url(http://mypet.guru/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/fluffy-cats-009.jpg) no-repeat right center;
}
#highlights .high-venas .image {
    background: url(http://mypet.guru/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/fluffy-cats-009.jpg) no-repeat right center;
}
#highlights .high-cirugiaCalvicie .image {
    background: url(http://mypet.guru/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/fluffy-cats-009.jpg) no-repeat right center;
}
#highlights .high-tratamientoCalvicie .image {
    background: url(http://mypet.guru/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/fluffy-cats-009.jpg) no-repeat right center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Everything remains same just add transition to p and image element.

```
#highlights .image {
    height:100%;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease; // increase 0.5s to whatever you wish in order to add more smoothness
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#highlights p {
    background-color: white;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 60px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    opacity:0.7;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
```